# How do I determine Shift+Left Click modal operator?

Tags: python, operator

I would like to determine if `Left Click` + `Shift` pressed at the same time in `event.type` in a modal operator. I also want to treat `Left Click` itself as a separate `event.type` than one with the Shift.

I looked around and I can t seem to find an answer. I am wondering how this is done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong.. but this is my understanding (and it seems to work for me):

There is nothing as simultaneous with the events. Even if you press shift and click simultaneously, there are actually four separate events. 1) `event.type = 'LEFT_SHIFT'` with `event.value = 'PRESS'` 2) `event.type = 'LEFTMOUSE'` and `event.value = 'PRESS'` 3) `event.type = 'LEFT_SHIFT'` & `event.value = 'RELEASE'` 2) `event.type = 'LEFTMOUSE'` and `event.value = 'RELEASE'` (the order might change depending on what comes first).

There is also a `CLICK` `event.value` available for `LEFTMOUSE` `event.type` that combines `PRESS` and `RELEASE`.

So, to answer your question, you would basically need to store an instance variable like `self.shift` and set / reset its value on `event.value == 'PRESS'` / `event.value == 'RELEASE'`. You can check in your function whether with the mouse press event occurred when `self.shift` was `True`.

If you figure out a better way to do this, I would be interested to know :)

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.